# Mocker: patched funciton being ignored during pytest execution

Tags: mocking, pytest, patch

I'm trying to mock this function:

`def check_type(xxx) -> Tuple[bool, str]:`

By doing this:

`@patch('module.check_type', return_value=True)`

But, the original function keeps being called.

Tried changing the module path in the patch:

`@patch('top_folder.module.check_type', return_value=True)`
`@patch('check_type', return_value=True)`

And tried changing the returned value to match the function definition:

`@patch('module.check_type', return_value=[True, 'foo'])`

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the functions 'path' should not be its location, but the path of the module that uses it.

This is how I was trying, the 'get_attribute' function was located inside a file named 'check_types', in the folder 'create_tst'.

@patch('create_tst.check_types.get_attribute_type', return_value='INT')

And the file that uses it, is named 'test_worksheet', in the same folder 'create_tst'.
Then, the patch should be done using the 'calling' module's path.

@patch('create_tst.test_worksheet.get_attribute_type', return_value='INT')